# How can I convert a vector containing entries [[[int int]] ...] into a vector containing entries [[int int] ...] in python/numpy?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I have data in a numpy vector that looks like this:

```
 [[[1119   15]]

 [[1125   27]]

 [[1129   43]]

 [[1131   62]]

 [[1131   87]]

 [[1141  234]]

 ...]
```

These are supposed to be a set of points that I can use to represent a curve, but instead each point [int, int] seems to be encapsulated inside another vector.  I.E.:  I have [[1   1]] instead of [1   1].

This data was given to me by an opencv function `cv2.approxPolyDP` after I fed it a `contour', and I need to work with it.  I think the function basically has given me what it thinks is a set of curves, but here each curve only contains one point [int int] which doesn't really make sense.  A curve with one point is not a curve, it's a point.

Is there any way to convert [[int   int]] to [int   int] in this case?

Comment: You are probably looking for [`np.squeeze`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the shape of this array. It probably is `(n, 1, 2)`.

`reshape` it to `(n,2)`.  `x.reshape(-1,2)` is a handy shortcut, saving you the work of determining `n`.  `squeeze` also gits rid of the singular dimension.

Answer (score 2):

Probably it is not optimal solution but you can do this:

```
import numpy as np

# example 

a = np.array( [ [[1119, 15]], [[1125, 27]], [[1129, 43]] ] )

# convert

a = np.array( [ x[0] for x in a ] )

print a

[[1119   15]
 [1125   27]
 [1129   43]]
```

---

**EDIT:**

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array( [ [[1119, 15]], [[1125, 27]], [[1129, 143]] ] )

size = len(a)

a = a.reshape([size,2])

print a

    [[1119   15]
     [1125   27]
     [1129   43]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the second parameter in **approxPolyDP** is too big.
Notice that the following code doesn't make it small all the time:

```
epsilon = 0.1*arcLength(contour,True)
polygon = approxPolyDP(contour, epsilon, True)
```

When the edge of contour gets noisy, the arc length of the contour returned by **arcLength** can be very very big, which yields a still very big epsilon after being multiplied by 0.1 and thus make **approxPolyDP** simplify the entire contour into one single point.